# Android hardware back button exits app on react navigation

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, back-button

I am using react navigation {create stack navigator} and so many pages. When I press hardware back button it **exits** app instead of **going back**.

My friend said that it is may be because of **firebase** (which I use for autheticating *(no db)*). Version of firebase 5.3.1 and he gave advice to install 5.0.0 (I've tried **npm install firebase@5.0.0 --save**, but it shows some errors and hence is not installed)

And I've asked many of my friends and hardware back button returns goBack, but not for me

> What should I do? I've tried to use BackHandler but I'm confused,so it doesn't work

**react 16.3.1**

**react native 0.55.2**

**react navigation 2.9.3**

Answer (score 0):

Did you added an event listner with react navigation ?

Follow this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-android-back-button-handling.html) it's well detailed.

Comment: That link is not clear for me. Need I put this Custom Android back button behavior code on every page in order to **not exit** the app?

Comment: You have to make a custom component with that like described https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html then import it in the screen

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the npm [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) package. This issue can be fixed by changing the way you import firebase. **Use**:

```
import firebase from "@firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";
```

**Don't use** `import * as firebase from "firebase";` or `import firebase from "firebase";`

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4364#issue-327089661) for more details.